# Ubuntu Randomly Stopped Booting

Tags: boot, live-cd

I'm using Ubuntu since 2007 on A Dell Vostro 1510 and Ubuntu always did the job. I recently installed 11.10, its been working for the past two weeks with Gnome Shell.

It worked some one hour ago still and because the wireless didn't seem to pick networks in the new location I am at the moment, I rebooted my laptop.

Suddenly however, Ubuntu did *not* boot. The process goes through:

```
* PulseAudio configured for per-user sessions
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
* Starting CUPS printing spooler/server [OK]
* Starting ana(h)ronistic cron
* Stopping ana(h)ronistic cron [OK]
* Checking battery state ... [OK]
* Stopping System V runlevel compatibility [OK]
```

... and that's where it stops.

Now I am downloading a liveCD right now to save my data and with hope of fixing Ubuntu. But I'm not sure whether I will manage to do that, and besides I'd like to understand what's happening. Can someone help please?

Can I repair my installation using the LiveCD?

**edit:** I have tried to upgrade from liveCD (from 11.10 to 11.10) but stopped the process once it asked me for a user name and password (which doesn't make sense if one upgrades). Now as I try again, I don't even get the option to up grade any more. (Please help I'd like to salvage the data I have on my disk.)

**edit 2:** Now trying to boot it says "missing operating system".

**edit 3:** *This thread is abandoned by me, I simply made a new install.*

Comment: Did you run the Update Manager recently?

Comment: No, I've been travelling today and I was offline all the time and I rebooted several times today without issues.

Comment: @UriHerrera: I have seen your other answer on xubuntu not booting after some updates. In case I am mistaken about updating / booting, I'd like to know what you suggest.

Comment: In my case a Security Update for X.org brought my issue, it broke FGLRX so i had to use another PC to re install the driver   .

Comment: @UriHerrera: how can I find out what's broken and how can I fix anything using liveCD?

Comment: When you turn your computer on, have you tried going to recovery mode in GRUB or even booting into an older kernel build? It's usually the first thing I do when Ubuntu won't boot.

Comment: No Grub :( I tried to install it with the boot-repair application, but when it boots it simply says there's no OS. I think I'm going to make a clean install.

Comment: Well, i didn't look into it .. i just had this feeling that the update to X.org caused it, but since you didn't upgraded anything i wouldn't know what to say.. doing a clean install is for the better though, just remember to keep back ups of your files elsewhere.. in another partition or a cloud service.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, ***titaniumtux*** has a good response, I understand it's too late now, but in future what you should try first is booting an older kernel, which can be achieved by holding down the SHIFT key when you restart your computer and you will be greeted by the GRUB splash screen, at this point you can select an older kernel to try and boot from.

Comment: @titaniumtux: if you make it an answer, I'll take it.