# Xubuntu won't boot after applying Security Fixes

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu

After i was prompted by the Update manager to install some security fixes Xubuntu won't boot, I don't know which one of all the updates caused this, how can i look into this.?

I don't seem to have access to the internet in recovery with netroot even if the module is loaded, briefly I'm greeted with tty1 but soon thereafter it goes black and unresponsive.

Comment: Sorry you are having this problem. Do you know what was updated ? Can you boot an older kernel successfully? What version of xubuntu ?

Comment: I don't remmember all the updates some were xorg,cups,lightdm..i can't boot with neither kernel i had for now i only have 3.2.4 installed, it's Xubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I wonder if that's similar to [my issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102343/ubuntu-randomly-stopped-booting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, apparently a recent update to X.org killed FGLRX wrecking havoc among my PC, luckily i have a spare PC which is generic enough to boot  off the affected system, removed FGLRX then restarted, re isntalled it again, and now it happily boots.

Update Manager should've warned me about this happening...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the grub menu at start up?

If you do, you can go into recovery mode, use the option to fix/repair broken packages, if you have a ethernet connection, it will fix these packages, if you don't have access to this, and it is xubuntu 11.10, then load the cd, go to install, choose upgrade install, tell the installer to download all updates, and thrid party software, this installer will save all your personal settings, and files, it will basically erase the os, and re-install it, after install is complete, it will download all updates, security updates, and programs you downloaded, and install them all, This would basically be exactly what fixing broken packages would do, redownload the packages and install them again.  It is possible that a package you currently had, caused part of a package to not be installed correctly, possibly one that was being updated, this in turn caused the OS not to be able to load.

Comment: Yes i have access to the Grub menu, I can't do a repair as i don't have internet access as i mentioned in my question the module is set to load but it won't load, I've been doing exactly that, Install Xubuntu, do the Upgrade, and have come to the same results one of the updates keeps on killing my system but since there's more than 1 upgrade available it's going to take me forever to track the culprit.

Comment: I tried the upgrade install for [a similar issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102343/ubuntu-randomly-stopped-booting) but stopped when the upgrade asked me for a new user name and password (which I found odd) and now the liveCD doesn't provide the option to upgrade any more. (Sorry if I seem to hijack this question, but my problem seems similar and the answer conflicting with my experience.)